# split() for a dataframe inside a list (in R) - how to omit

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes and I need to split each of them by a factor variable.

```
 myList <- list(df1 = data.frame(A = sample(10), B = factor(rep(1:2))), 
                df2 = data.frame(A = sample(10), B = factor(rep(1:2))))
```

This is what I tried:

```
 TMP <- lapply(myList, function(x){x <- split(x, x$B)})
```

There is a minor problem as the factor variable remains in the resulting split dataframes. How can I prevent that from happening? I know several ways to omit that column afterwards, but I'm looking for a neater solution. I also think that split() is intended to leave out that factor variable.

Comment: `lapply(myList, function(x){split(x[-2], x$B)})`?

Comment: It is simple and it works! An option in split() that does it could be useful I think.

Comment: `split` can be used to split based on vectors not contained in the data frame. I'm guessing that's a reason why `split` will not presume if the value it uses is something that is in a data frame in the first place, much less offers to drop it.